# I would like to put the information to add in jpanel jscrollpane when you click each tree node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I would like to put the information to add in jpanel jscrollpane when you click each tree node... Please...!!!

1.I want to control that state selected tree node at Tree.java where Frame.java

Tree.java

```
package pms;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class Tree extends JTree {
private JTree tree;
public static int selectItem = 0;

public JTree CreateTree() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Management");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode bigLeaf1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Generl Affair");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode bigLeaf2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Personal Affair");
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Recruit");
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test");

    bigLeaf1.add(leaf2);
    bigLeaf2.add(leaf3);
    root.add(bigLeaf1);
    root.add(bigLeaf2);
    tree = new JTree(root);

    tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            TreePath tp = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (e.getClickCount() >= 2) {
                if (tp.getLastPathComponent() == leaf2) {
                    selectItem = 2;
                    System.out.println(selectItem);
                } else if (tp.getLastPathComponent() == leaf3) {
                    selectItem = 3;
                    System.out.println(selectItem);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return tree;
    }

    public int selectedItem() {
        return selectItem;
    }
}
```

Frame.java

```
package pms;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    static int v = ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
    static int h = ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED;
    private JPanel pan1, pan2, pan3, pan4;
    public static JScrollPane jsp2;
    public Tree tree;
    public static ArrayList<Viewer> ViewArr = new ArrayList<Viewer>();
    public static int selectItem = 0;

    public Frame() {
        setTitle("Personal Management System");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null); // AbsoulteLayout

        /** Create MenuBar */
        menuBar menubar = new menuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar.CreateMenuBar());

        pan1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout()); // TreeNode ScrollPane
        pan2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // toolbar & ScrollPane2
        pan1.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 950); // Fixed Panel Size
        pan2.setBounds(350, 0, 1300, 950);
        getContentPane().add(pan1);
        getContentPane().add(pan2);

        /** Create Tree */
        tree = new Tree();

        JScrollPane jsp1 = new JScrollPane(tree.CreateTree(), v, h);
        pan1.add(jsp1);

        /** Create toolbar Panel */
        pan3 = new toolBar().CreateToolbar();
        pan2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pan2.add(pan3, "North");

        /** Create viewer ScrollPane */
        jsp2 = new JScrollPane(v, h);
        jsp2.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        pan2.add(jsp2, "East");
        setSize(1300, 950);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void ShowInterViewer() {
        selectItem = tree.selectedItem();
        try {
            if (selectItem == 2) {
                System.out.println("222");
            } else if (selectItem == 3) {
                System.out.println("333");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.run();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ShowInterViewer();
    }
}
```

Viewer.java

```
    package pms;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Viewer extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private JPanel jp;
    private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5, tf6;
    private JLabel lb1, lb2, lb3, lb4, lb5, lb6;
    private JButton btn1;
    private String name, sex, pass, phone, picturePath, filePath;
    private Date birthday, interviewDate;

    public Viewer(String name, Date birthday, String sex, Date interviewDate, String pass, String phone) {
        setName(name);
        setSex(sex);
        setPass(pass);
        setPass(pass);
        CreateViewer();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        if(sex.equals("M")){
            this.sex = "남자";
        }else if(sex.equals("W")){
            this.sex = "여자";
        }
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        if(pass.equals("Y")){
            this.pass = "합격";
        }else if(pass.equals("N")){
            this.pass = "불합격";
        }
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPicturePath() {
        return picturePath;
    }

    public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) {
        this.picturePath = picturePath;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Date getInterviewDate() {
        return interviewDate;
    }

    public void setInterviewDate(Date interviewDate) {
        this.interviewDate = interviewDate;
    }

    public JPanel CreateViewer(){
        jp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        tf1 = new JTextField(getName());
        tf1.setColumns(20);
        //tf1.setBounds(50,50,10,10);
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf2.setColumns(20);
        tf3 = new JTextField();
        tf3.setColumns(20);
        tf4 = new JTextField();
        tf4.setColumns(20);
        tf5 = new JTextField();
        tf5.setColumns(20);
        tf6 = new JTextField();
        tf6.setColumns(20);

        lb1 = new JLabel("이름");
        lb2 = new JLabel("생년월일");
        lb3 = new JLabel("성별");
        lb4 = new JLabel("면접일자");
        lb5 = new JLabel("합격여부");
        lb6 = new JLabel("연락처");

        btn1 = new JButton("이력서 보기");



        jp.add(tf1);
        jp.add(tf2);
        jp.add(tf3);
        jp.add(tf4);
        jp.add(tf5);
        jp.add(tf6);
        jp.add(lb1);
        jp.add(lb2);
        jp.add(lb3);
        jp.add(lb4);
        jp.add(lb5);
        jp.add(lb6);
        jp.add(btn1);

        return jp;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: *"I would like to put the information to add in jpanel jscrollpane when you click each tree node..."*  Cool.  Go for it!  But I don't see any question here unless it is *'Can you show me how to do that?'* which is 'too broad' for this Q&A site.

Comment: `...setLayout(null); // AbsoulteLayout`  More like an absolute cluster-f*ck.  Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you really don't need to extend a `JTree`, you're not adding any new functionality to the class (nor are you actually using it), instead, just create an instance of `JTree` and pass it an instance a `TreeModel` which models your data.

This means that you are free to add a `TreeListSelection` to the `JTree`, which will tell you when the selection changes.  From the resulting `TreeSelectionEvent` you can get the selected `path`, which will tell you the components which are selected from the root to the currently selected node.  You can then use `getLastPathComponent` to get the last node in the path (which will be the selected node).

Once you have this information, you can then make decisions about how best you should feed it to the corresponding view.  Because you're using `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, you can associate a `userObject` with it, which makes it easier to store complex data with each node.

Based on your `Viewer` class, it would seem that the data is pretty commonailised, in that case I would consider creating POJO which maintains all the associated data and simply apply it to the `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, this way you can use `getUserObject` to extract it easily.  You then simply pass this object to the `Viewer` panel (via some kind of setter) and let the viewer update it's own state accordingly

Have a look at [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for more details

For example...

[image: Tree]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class InterviewBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InterviewBrowser();
    }

    public InterviewBrowser() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Management");
                DefaultMutableTreeNode bigLeaf1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Generl Affair");
                DefaultMutableTreeNode bigLeaf2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Personal Affair");
                DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new InterviewHistory(
                                "Bob",
                                new Date(LocalDate.of(1972, Month.MARCH, 8).toEpochDay()),
                                Sex.MALE,
                                new Date(LocalDate.of(2015, Month.AUGUST, 10).toEpochDay()),
                                false,
                                "123456789"));
                DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new InterviewHistory(
                                "Jane",
                                new Date(LocalDate.of(1973, Month.JANUARY, 1).toEpochDay()),
                                Sex.FEMALE,
                                new Date(LocalDate.of(2015, Month.AUGUST, 10).toEpochDay()),
                                true,
                                "87654321"));

                bigLeaf1.add(leaf2);
                bigLeaf2.add(leaf3);
                root.add(bigLeaf1);
                root.add(bigLeaf2);
                DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

                JTree tree = new JTree(model);

                Viewer viewer = new Viewer();

                tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
                        TreePath path = e.getPath();
                        Object lastPathComponent = path.getLastPathComponent();
                        if (lastPathComponent instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
                            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) lastPathComponent;
                            Object userObject = node.getUserObject();
                            if (userObject instanceof InterviewHistory) {
                                InterviewHistory history = (InterviewHistory) userObject;
                                viewer.setHistory(history);
                            } else {
                                viewer.setHistory(null);
                            }
                        } else {
                            viewer.setHistory(null);
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.add(viewer);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum Sex {

        MALE,
        FEMALE
    }

    public class InterviewHistory {

        private String name;
        private Date birthDate;
        private Sex sex;
        private Date interviewDate;
        private boolean passed;
        private String phone;

        public InterviewHistory(String name, Date birthDate, Sex sex, Date interviewDate, boolean passed, String phone) {
            this.name = name;
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.interviewDate = interviewDate;
            this.passed = passed;
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Date getBirthDate() {
            return birthDate;
        }

        public Sex getSex() {
            return sex;
        }

        public Date getInterviewDate() {
            return interviewDate;
        }

        public boolean didPass() {
            return passed;
        }

        public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }

    }

    public static class Viewer extends JPanel {

        public static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

        private JTextField name;
        private JTextField dateOfBirth;
        private JLabel sex;
        private JTextField dateOfInterview;
        private JCheckBox passed;
        private JTextField phone;

        public Viewer() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            add(new JLabel("Name: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Date of birth: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Sex: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Date of Interview: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Passed interview: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Phone: "), gbc);

            name = new JTextField(25);
            dateOfBirth = new JTextField(10);
            sex = new JLabel("?");
            dateOfInterview = new JTextField(10);
            passed = new JCheckBox();
            phone = new JTextField(9);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(name, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(dateOfBirth, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(sex, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(dateOfInterview, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(passed, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(phone, gbc);

        }

        public void setHistory(InterviewHistory history) {
            name.setText(history == null ? null : history.getName());
            dateOfBirth.setText(history == null ? null : DATE_FORMAT.format(history.getBirthDate()));
            sex.setText(history == null ? "?" : history.getSex().name());
            dateOfInterview.setText(history == null ? null : DATE_FORMAT.format(history.getInterviewDate()));
            passed.setSelected(history == null ? false : history.didPass());
            phone.setText(history == null ? "?" : history.getPhone());
        }

    }
}
```

DO NOT rely on the state of `static` variables, it is WAY to easy for that state not to reflect reality, instead, rely on actual known values you can ascertain from the state of the view/model.

The purpose of any model is to provide a mechanism for you to display your data, you should use it to wrap your data directly, rather the trying to guess at the state of the UI or model and then look up the data separately (IMHO)

Comment: First, Thank you for answer! :)
I want to Control jpanel to node's change at Function ShowInterViewer() 
What can i???

Comment: Nothing, I wouldn't do it that way, you are relying on `static` variables whose state you can't guarantee

Comment: Ok! Thaks for your sincere answer!! :) I trying to way for your answer!

Comment: O.M.G!!!! I see the  new World!!! 
I learn it is right that in this way coded !!! 
Very very Thank you!!!! 
I trying and learning your code!