# Java Swing > Calling specific powershell script by selecting DefaultMutableTreeNode from Jtree model

Tags: java, swing, powershell, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

I'm having my first time with java Swing and I wondering if can I add values for each DefaultMutableTreeNode and refer to them by selecting specific node?

e.g. Calling specific powershell script by selecting node from Jtree model (1 node = 1 script).
I'm really newbie and I will be greatful if somebody could explain or redirected me to some solution ;p

```
private JTree setTab2Tree() {
    JTree tree;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new  DefaultMutableTreeNode("Customers");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode webClient = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Web");
    webClient.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Person Customer"));
    webClient.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Firm Customer"));
    DefaultMutableTreeNode appClient = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("App");
    appClient.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Person Customer"));
    appClient.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Firm Customer"));
    root.insert(webClient, 0);
    root.insert(appClient, 1);
    tree = new JTree(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
        tree.expandRow(i);
    }
    tree.setRootVisible(false);
    tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new MainTree.SelectionListener());
    tree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    add(new JScrollPane(tree));
}
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- nobody wants to read through hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can associate an object with each node (look for userObject in the docs)

Comment: You're right. Sorry, my bad and thanks for the tip

Comment: [As an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911382/i-would-like-to-put-the-information-to-add-in-jpanel-jscrollpane-when-you-click/31911449#31911449)

Comment: Yes that's what i needed! Thank you @MadProgrammer Just whooaa You're a true hero :)

Comment: @Archie Glad I could help somebody ;)